# General Browser shortcut to move cursor to primary search field on any webpage?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, website

**Question**:
When a webpage has finished loading: Is there a shortcut to make the cursor jump to the "primary" search form?

**Background**:
Many webpages have a search input form for writing text to search for. However to get to the input form you often need to use your mouse, or press the "tab" button many times. This is the case even on websites on which the keyboard are almost exclusively used for to input the search feature. The need for this shortcut exists on many websites but not all.

Examples are:

- pubmed.gov        need to press tab 10 times to get to search bar
  (bad)
- cnn.com           need to press tab 10 times to get to search
  bar (bad)
- reddit.com        need to press tab 60+ times to get to
  search bar (bad)
- https://superuser.com/ cursor jumps to primary search form after 1 click on tab(very good)
- google.com        cursor automatically lands in search form (very good)

**Software used**

If *any* browser can do this I would be happy to switch.

Comment: This [lifehacker reference](https://lifehacker.com/jump-quickly-to-text-fields-in-firefox-5210063) is helpful in firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt any browser/extension can automatically figure out which is the *primary* search field on any web page, especially when multiple text fields may be present.

The best method I can think of is to use the [Fox Input](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fox-input/) add-on for Firefox:

> This extension provides a hotkey to focus on the input field on a webpage. The default hotkeys are Alt-I (go to the next text input field) and Alt-J (go to the previous one), but you can change them in the setting window.

[image: 1]

This should at least cut down the key-presses required, and if only one text field exists on the page a single <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact same problem. Having to press Tab 10 times or more is really subobtimal. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an extension that would modify the behaviour of Tab so that pressing it once would focus the search bar immediately. Well, long story short I ended up building my own Google Chrome Extension that does exactly that. Feel free to check it out on the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-box-focus-hit-tab/amgmdnojamodmpfjaokfgpijhpcednjm)!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge fan of Vimium, and it can do this with the "gi" command. I find it's sometimes hit and miss, especially depending on whether the page supports Vimium. In general, once you learn Vimium shortcuts you rarely have to take your hands off the keyboard while browsing/researching, which is wonderful. The Chrome extension is here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en

It's also available for Firefox.

Comment: I already use Vimium but did not know about this, so this is great :)